# What is context.dispatch in feathers.js

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-hook

I read the feathersjs API documentation. ([this](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#context-dispatch))
But I can't understand what is the `context.dispatch`. and what does this do.

> context.dispatch is a writeable, optional property and contains a "safe" version of the data that should be sent to any client.
>   If context.dispatch has not been set context.result will be sent to the client instead.

What is the "safe" version means?
When will I want to use it?

Comment: It’s not a well known or much used feature andI personally think it is confusing and only potentially useful in very specific use cases. Generally, if `context.dispatch` is set, THAT value is returned and not `hook.result`, but only for external providers (REST, socket.io)

Comment: Basically, don’t use it. I haven’t had a need for it in two years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "safe" version is what a client can see and is specifically important for hiding fields - like the password - in real-time events. For example, if - on the server - you do:

```
app.service('users').patch(user.id, { enabled: false })
```

The return value will include the hashed `password` even though it is using the [protect hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#protect-fields) because it is an internal call.

However, `context.dispatch` will not include the password and the `patched` [real-time event](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html) will only send back the safe data to the client.

Comment: I could finally understand this use cases and how to use feathers-hooks-common's utils using context.dispatch. Thank you @Daff !